# Getting "expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token" when trying to allocate memory with new and copy constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to allocate memory for an array of unknown size that is a datamember of a class.
The datamember is:

```
PassengerCompartment** pass_comp;
```

In the copy constructor of the class (Plane) that I want to allocate the array, I have this:
("given" is a const Plane&)

```
pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment*[given.NOofAlloc_PasCom];
for (int i=0; i < NOofAlloc_PasCom; i++)
{
     pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment( given.(*pass_comp[i]) );
}
```

And I am getting this compiler error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

at this line:

```
pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment( given.(*pass_comp[i]) );
```

( the "(" that is mentioned, is the 1st one, after PassengerCompartment)

What have I done wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How do you know it's the first bracket?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I'm getting this: `objects.cpp:552:50: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token`. "50" tells me that. Doesn't it?

Comment: What is it `given`? Anyway it's not possible that `pass_comp` is access by `given` this way.  Should it be something like `pass_comp[i] = new PassengerCompartment( <arguments> );`?

Comment: ("given" is a const Plane&) The class in discussion is Class Plane.
I didn't quite understand what you say here: "Anyway it's not possible that pass_comp is access by given this way."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is surely not the first bracket, but the second, as `given.(*pass_comp[i])` is not valid syntax. Maybe you meant `*given.pass_comp[i]` (which dereferences `given.pass_comp[i]`)?

Oh, and you probably also want `pass_comp[i]` instead of `pass_comp` before the assignment operator.

Comment: About the pass_comp[i], that's what I have, typo here;)
Thank you very much for the help. That was it `*given.pass_comp[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

`pass_comp` is a pointer to pointer. If you assign it with new, the compiler expects to have `pass_comp = new Xxx*;`.

I guess what you want is `pass_comp[i] = new Xxx();` as you have already assigned `pass_comp` once.

**Edit:** Or maybe, what you finaly want is (note the type of `pass_comp` is changed) to have only one allocation?

```
PassengerCompartment* pass_comp;
pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment[given.NOofAlloc_PasCom];
```

Comment: Isn't this `pass_comp[i] = new Xxx();` what I am doing here: `pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment( given.(*pass_comp[i]) );` ?

Comment: You have first to allocate room for your pointers array, and assign it to your `pass_comp` pointer. Then, you allocate each object and assign it to each entry in your pointers array.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, allocating pointer array and then allocating new Passenger Compartments. The problem was the `given.(*pass_comp[i])`. Really stupid of me to do that :/

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment*[given.NOofAlloc_PasCom];
for (int i=0; i < given.NOofAlloc_PasCom; i++)
{
     pass_comp[i] = new PassengerCompartment(*given.pass_comp[i]);
}
```

There you are initializing an array of given.NOofAlloc_PasCom pointers to PassengerCompartment, and then initializing each with a copy of the contents of given.pass_comp.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
pass_comp = new PassengerCompartment( given.(*pass_comp[i]) );
```

to

```
pass_comp[i] = new PassengerCompartment( *given.pass_comp[i] );
```